# Show that Operator is symmetric

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $l^2_0:=\{a=(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^2 \colon a_1=0\}$ where all the elements in the sequence are real.

Given the scalar product $\langle a,b\rangle =\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_jb_j$ show that the operator

$(Aa)_j:=\frac{a_{j+1}+a_{j-1}}{2}, \ j\ge 2$ is symmetric.

We have

$\langle Aa,b\rangle = \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{a_{j+1}+a_{j-1}}{2}b_j=\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{a_{j+1}b_j+a_jb_{j+1}}{2}$ by shifting the index.

I am not sure what I am missing, but I can not show the symmetry.

Comment: Shift again to obtain $\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{a_{j+1}b_j+a_jb_{j+1}}{2}=\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{b_{j+1}a_j+b_ja_{j+1}}{2}= \sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{b_{j+1}+b_{j-1}}{2}a_j=\langle a,Ab\rangle$?

Comment: @ThePhenotype Would there be a simple way to show, that the operator cannot have eigenvalues? My proof seems a bit over the top for this.